# Not sure how to use typenum type in match

Tags: rust

I'm doing a DNS server, to have a fine-grained control I'm using typenum when I need to use like 3 or 4 bits integer.

```py
use typenum::U4;

pub fn from_num(num: U4) -> ResultCode {
        match num {
            0 => ResultCode::NOERROR,
            1 => ResultCode::FORMERR,
            2 => ResultCode::SERVFAIL,
            3 => ResultCode::NXDOMAIN,
            4 => ResultCode::NOTIMP,
            5 => ResultCode::REFUSED,
            _ => panic!("Invalid ResultCode: {}", num),
        }
}
```

0 is seen as integer, not U4

I tried `U4::new(0)` and `0U4` but It not worked.

Comment: Can you please provide additional information, I would like to see the definition of U4, I also don't entirely understand what exactly you are trying to do? Finally, can you specify what exactly does wrong, can you provide the error message if there is one?

Comment: @Plegeus the error is a mismatched types
expected struct `UInt<UInt<UInt<UTerm, B1>, B0>, B0>`
found type `{integer}`

Comment: Have you tested with other numbers, please can you give the definition of U4, Uint and UTerm?

Comment: Not sure what's unclear here - `U4` is specifically shown as imported from `typenum`, and `UInt` and `UTerm` are its implementation details (also from `typenum`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the role of `typenum`. It's not an implementation for arbitrary-sized integers, it's an implementation for *type-level* integers. This means, in particular, that `U4` is not a four-bit integer. It's a type representing integer number 4.

For your goal, you're probably looking for [`ux` crate](https://docs.rs/ux/0.1.5/ux/index.html), which allows exactly the arbitarily-sized integer types. Note however that these arbitrary sizes are only arbitrary in terms of API and invariants, not storage - you still can't pack two `u4`s in one byte, since they must be addressable independently.

For matching specifically, you can use [`impl From<u4> for u8`](https://docs.rs/ux/0.1.5/ux/struct.u4.html#impl-From%3Cu4%3E-for-u8) and do the following:

```
match num.into() {
    // Use type suffix here to guide inference
    // You could also do `match u8::from(num)` instead
    0u8 => ResultCode::NOERROR,
    1 => ResultCode::FORMERR,
    2 => ResultCode::SERVFAIL,
    3 => ResultCode::NXDOMAIN,
    4 => ResultCode::NOTIMP,
    5 => ResultCode::REFUSED,
    _ => panic!("Invalid ResultCode: {}", num),
}
```

Comment: This is not a `From` implementation, it's a free function, just as OP did originally. You point is valid, though.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the last sentence before the code block. I thought you were suggesting a `From` implementation for `ResultCode`. That's what I get for trying to comprehend text this late.